# Mysql configuration for using some caching

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I use JDBC Java MySQL driver, but I found it is some how slow in cases when I run tests where I do drop table populate data and read it from straight after. data appears not there, But is I do delay for some second - data is there. I am afraid that not only Tests works this way and production code also may not read last data written.

So I need read just after written. without delay.

Would some caching help? Googled for and tried  manuals still could not find answer.

here is some code i do use for inserting and retrieving:

```
private Connection conn = null;
private Statement stmt0;
private Statement stmt1;

@Inject
public DBConnectorMysql(@Named("JDBC_URL") String url, @Named("JDBC_CRED") String creds) throws SQLException {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + creds);
    stmt0 = conn.createStatement();
    stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
}

@Override
public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) throws SQLException {
    return stmt0.executeQuery(query);
}

@Override
public int executeUpdate(String query, String... values) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    int i = 0;
    for (String s: values){
        stmt.setString( ++i, s );
    }
    stmt.executeUpdate();

    int newId = -1;
    ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
    if (rs.next()) {
        newId = rs.getInt(1);
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    return newId;
}
```

I do use Java SE with [Mysql driver](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)

I actively use three tables without foreign key.

Comment: Could you share some more details? Are you working with plain Java or with servers, Java EE etc? Moreover, could you give some indication about how many table rows you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems that you use multiple statement / prepared statement objects from the same connection that are open at the same time. This may have unexpected results (the JDBC spec doesn't really specify how this is handled, it's down to each vendor's implementation and I vaguelly recall a similar behaviour with an older version of MySQL/JDBC connector).

You should make sure that only one of them is open at any time. You could replace all your statements with a simple one, but as I see that's not practical since you want both Statement in `executeQuery` and a PreparedStatement in `executeUpdate`.

Otherwise you can move the `createStatement` calls inside the methods that use them. The best practice for `executeQuery` would be to return an ArrayList with your results (and close the ResultSet and stmt0 before returning).

Another, less elegant solution would be to write a `closeQuery` method that closes stmt0 after you're done with the ResultSet from executeQuery.

<s>You have to call `conn.commit()` before `rs.close()` in order for your changes to take effect.</s>